# Adding a point label to a moving arrow vector

Tags: graphics, manipulate

Consider:

```
Manipulate[Graphics[{Blue,
   Arrow[{{0, 0}, u}], 
   Text[Style[Pane["u", ImageMargins -> 1], 14, Background -> White], 
    0.5 u], Arrow[{{0, 0}, v}],
   Text[Style[Pane["v", ImageMargins -> 1], 14, Background -> White], 
    0.5 v],
   {Gray, Arrow[{u, u + v}], Arrow[{v, u + v}]},
   {Red, Arrow[{{0, 0}, u + v}],
    Text[Style[Pane["u + v", ImageMargins -> 1], 14, 
      Background -> White], 0.5 (u + v)]},
   {Black, 
    If[labels, 
     Text[Style[Pane[u[[1]], ImageMargins -> 1], 14, 
       Background -> White], u]]
    }},
  Axes -> True, PlotRange -> 3, Ticks -> None],
 {{u, {1, 2}}, Locator, Appearance -> None},
 {{v, {2, 1}}, Locator, Appearance -> None},
 {labels, {False, True}}]
```

Which gives the following image.

[image]

Now, it's this line where I am having trouble.

```
{Black, 
        If[labels, 
         Text[Style[Pane[u[[1]], ImageMargins -> 1], 14, 
           Background -> White], u]]
        }
```

What I'd like to do is place the components of the vector u at its arrow tip (like this: (-3,2)) when the "labels" checkbox is checked.

Any thoughts?

Comment: `Pane[u, ...` instead of `Pane[u[[1]], ...`?

Comment: Pane[StringReplace[ToString[u], {"{" -> "(", "}" -> ")"}],...?

Comment: @Algohi: Both of these answers are extremely helpful and both teach me something new.

Comment: @belisarius: May I ask one more question? Suppose I want my locators to move only in increments of plus or minus one in either the x- or y-direction. How would I adjust the line  {{u, {1, 2}}, Locator, Appearance -> None} ?

Comment: `{{u, {1, 2}}, {-3, -3}, {3, 3}, {1, 1}, Locator, Appearance -> None}`

Comment: @Karsten: Excellent. Works great! Thanks.